# How to calculate $\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right)$ : simplification to real numbers.

Tags: trigonometry

I don't know if there is a general rule to the expression $\cos(k \pi /n)$.

However write $\cos(k \pi /n)$ in terms of real numbers like square root numbers and something like this?

As an example :

Suppose we want to calculate $\cos( \pi /12)$. From MathWorld's ["Trigonometry Angles -- $\pi/12$"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi12.html) entry, we obtain

$$\cos\frac{\pi}{12}\;=\; \frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt {6}+ \sqrt {2}\right)$$

But what would happen if the function is like this: $\cos\frac{17 \pi}{12}$ ?

It's clear that we can factor $17$ then we apply $\cos(a)\cos(b)$ but $\cos(17)$ is heavy little bit.

Any other assumptions?

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\cos(ab) \neq \cos(a)\cdot\cos(b)$, so calculating $\cos(17)$ isn't at issue here. Instead, you can start with $$\cos 17 x = \cos( x + 16 x) = \cos x \cos 16 x - \sin x \sin 16 x$$ Then re-write $\cos 16x$ and $\sin 16x$ in terms of $\cos 15x$ and $\sin 15 x$, and then $\cos 14 x$ and $\sin 14 x$, and then $\cos 13x$ and $\sin 13x$, etc, etc, etc, until everything is reduced to $\cos 1x$ and $\sin 1x$. It's a lot of work to do step by step; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles) for how to jump to the end.

Comment: Although it is off the topic, I would also like to share with you this: http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf 
We can see that in general, it is possible to express $\sin \theta$ in surd form. But the way to do so could be troublesome, judging from the messy results.

Comment: @Blue  thank you very much to your interettings and help

Comment: @LeeKM thank you very much to your interettings and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at [the De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula), by which you can express $\cos(k\pi/n)$ as a polynomial of $\cos(\pi/n)$ and $\sin(\pi/n)$. For a general question of how to express $\cos(\pi/n)$ by radicals, you can have a look at [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory).

But if you only need to calculate $\cos(17\pi/12)$, that is easy, since
$$\cos(17\pi/12)=\cos(3\pi/2-\pi/12).$$

Comment: then we use cos(a-b)=cos(a)sin(b)+sin(a)cos(b)
cos(3pi/2)=0 and sin(3pi/2)=-1
after this we simplify the terms which consist pi/12 by cos(b)=cos(pi/12)=1/4(sqrt(6)+sqrt(2) and sin(b)=sin(pi/12)=1/4(sqrt(6)-sqrt(2)